# PrimeNG DataTable; Destinguish between '[(selection)]' and the 'onRowClick' event handler

Tags: angular, primeng

I am currently using primeNG to display a list of employees.
I want to click on them for editing and i have got a column with comboboxes for selecting multiple employees for deleting multiple employees.
The problem is that if I click on a combobox the ´onRowClick´ handler also fires. Which is something I do not like as the edit dialog is appearing then.
Is there a way to distinguish between these two like column-only event handlers?

**My Table**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="employees" [(selection)]="selectedEmployees" (onRowClick)="routeToEmployee($event)">
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [field]="col.field" [header] = "col.header"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: The onRowClick just delivers the row data and the browser event. Unfortunately none of them contains the clicked column.

Comment: Yes, I just checked in their source code ... what a shame :(

Comment: But I don't know what to do now to realise my task. The only ways I could imaginge were sending a feature request or I replace the `onRowClick` with `onRowDblClick`. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You can run stopPropagation() on checkbox click.

Example:

```
<p-column styleClass="col-button" header="Select for restructurization">
    <template let-pLoan="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        <p-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" name="personalLoans" value="val1" [(ngModel)]="selectedLoansForRestruct"></p-checkbox>
    </template>
</p-column>
```